# Java recursion issue

Tags: java, recursion, series

Consider the following serie:

```
1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 32, 256, ...
```

I wrote this method in Java:

```
public static int Fibmul(int n){

        if (n == 1) return 1;
        else if (n == 0) return 0;
        else if (n < 0) return -1; // -1 means 'nil'
        else {
            n = Fibmul(n - 2) * Fibmul(n - 1);
        }
        return n;
    }
```

To calculate the serie just multiply the last two positions of the elements to obtain the next element, E.g Fibmul(4) should return 4 and Fibmul(6) should return 32.

But this code is wrong an I don't have more ideas, I have clear the algorithm over the paper but I don't know how to implement it.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "is wrong"? In what way? For what inputs?

Comment: How can the third term be 2 if the first two terms are both 1?

Comment: What is the rule you're trying to build?

Comment: If `n` is 2 you call and return `Fibmul(0)` which is 0 which renders the multiplication meaningless.

Comment: @khelwood , nice question. Sorry... I don't know... :(

Comment: Aren't you just calculating `2^(Fib(n))` in a complicated manner?

Comment: @Sweeper E. g. if you call Fibmul(5) it should be return 8, because is the result of Fibmul(4) * Fibmul(3)

Comment: If you hard code the first two terms to be 1 and 2 (instead of 0 and 1), you will get something like the sequence you're asking for.

Comment: @khelwood Did you mean control 1 and 2 such my first "if" steatment ?

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to get any higher numbers if your starting numbers are 0 and/or 1.
If your starting numbers are 1 and 2, you will get something like the sequence you described.

```
public static int Fibmul(int n){

    if (n == 1) return 2;
    else if (n == 0) return 1;
    else if (n < 0) return -1; // -1 means 'nil'
    else {
        n = Fibmul(n - 2) * Fibmul(n - 1);
    }
    return n;
}
```

This will give

```
1, 2, 2, 4, 8, 32, ...
```

It cannot start with `1,1,2` if you want to follow the rule you stated, because `1*1` does not equal 2.

NB: Your sequence is actually the ordinary Fibonacci series but with each term used as a power of 2.

```
Fibonacci: 0,    1,    1,    2,    3,    5,    13, ...
Fibmul: 2**0, 2**1, 2**1, 2**2, 2**3, 2**5, 2**13, ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @khelwood... was an stupid mistake. :(

Answer (score 1):

You simply need an extra solution for when `n == 2` because otherwise you'll remain stuck with `1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...`

```java
public static int Fibmul(int n) {
    if (n == 2)
        return 2;
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (n < 0)
        return -1; // -1 means 'nil'
    return Fibmul(n - 2) * Fibmul(n - 1);
}
```

Testing it works as expected

```
Fibmul(0) = 0
Fibmul(1) = 1
Fibmul(2) = 2
Fibmul(3) = 2
Fibmul(4) = 4
Fibmul(5) = 8
Fibmul(6) = 32
Fibmul(7) = 256
Fibmul(8) = 8192
Fibmul(9) = 2097152
```

Comment: Wow.... sorry.. I am really ashamed. Thanks a lot Yassin

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the 2 value. This should return 2, and the rest is fine:

```
else if (n == 2) return 2;
```

See here: https://code.sololearn.com/ca22A0a236a2

Comment: And then all subsequent terms will be 1, because you'd just be multiplying lots of 1s together.

Comment: ah yes! true! hmm

Comment: adding the 2 explicit will make this work